# Mbstring extension installation on godaddy server

Tags: server, php-extension, mbstring

> Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding(). How to install
>   mbstring extension installation on godaddy server?

Answer (score 1):

```
I have found the solution. We need to complete the following steps:

1.Login to your server  WHM as root
2.Search EasyApache or go to Software  menu after that  EasyApache
3. you can see there are some profile. click on customize profile default profile.
4. click on continue to second step
5. On “Step 2,” click on “Exhaustive Options”
6. Under PHP, check the checkbox for MBString
7. Proceed with Build & Compile Process
Make sure you wait for the build to complete.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating this thread as I went through a painful day trying to get this resolved.  The **mbstring** extension is used by Magento (I needed it for 1.9) and without it installed, the checkout process will fail, with the shopping cart failing to take the user to the *'Thanks for your order screen'* (although the order is sometimes created on the back-end successfully).  It was also creating an issue when hitting the *'Send Email'* button on the Admin panel on an Order, producing a 500 error.

In my log files, I was seeing the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() in
>   /home/yoursite/public_html/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 556

Searching for this error gave results that suggested I needed to enable the **mbstring** extension on the server, but with a GoDaddy hosted virtual server, I ran into a wall of frustration with the package not being found via the php install search, and their tech support unable to assist.  The above solution worked, although I will clarify the instructions below for the current WHM panel (Jan 2019):

1. Login to your server WHM as root.
2. Search EasyApache or go to the Software menu on the left and select 'EasyApache 4'.
3. You will see a list of profiles and at the top of the list, *'Currently Installed Packages'*.  Select the *'Customize'* button.
4. Select the '*PHP Extensions*' link or keep hitting '*Next*' until you reach the page.
5. In the search box, type *'string'*, you will see *'**php56-php-mbstring**'* and *'**php70-php-mbstring**'*; move the grey slider on the right to install each.
6. Continue to the *'Review'* tab.  Here you can simply hit *'Provision'* to install the extension.  You can also save these options as a custom profile if you'd like.
7. After the build has completed, the extension should be available on all your domains.

Hopefully this will save someone some time trying to figure this out!